# C stack overflow on Project Euler 27

Tags: haskell, recursion, fold

I just have started to learn Haskell and combine reading books and tutorials with solving problems from Project Euler. I have stuck on [Problem 27](http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=27) because I get "C stack overflow" error using this code:

**euler.hs**

```
divisors n = [x | x <- [1..n `div` 2], n `mod` x == 0] ++ [n]
is_prime n = divisors n == [1, n]
f a b = [n^2 + a * n + b | n <- [0..]]
primes_from_zero a b = length(takeWhile is_prime (f a b))
```

**command window**

this command gives Euler's coefficients 1 and 41 (40 primes in row)

```
foldr (max) (0, 0, 0) [(primes_from_zero a b, a, b) | a <- [0..10], b <- [0..50]]
```

this one fails with "C stack overflow" (I wanted to obtain coefficients -79 and 1601 also mentioned in the problem definition):

```
foldr (max) (0, 0, 0) [(primes_from_zero a b, a, b) | a <- [-100..0], b <- [1500..1700]]
```

Would you tell me, please, why does the error arise and how to resolve it? Thank you!

I use WinHugs.

Comment: http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Stack_overflow

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A "stack overflow" error means that the chain of function calls in your program (from the entry function down to the currently executing function) has grown too large. Most compilers and runtimes implement the call chain as a stack data structure—each element is a "stack frame" containing the local variables and context of a single function call—with a limited size.

Usually, a stack overflow means there's something wrong with a recursive function. For example, if a recursion never terminates, it will eventually hit the stack limit and "overflow." Even if a recursion is terminating, it may overflow if there are simply too many calls. This is often the case with very large lists, and seems to be the case with your example.

One way to avoid stack overflows in Haskell (and many other languages) is to write [tail-recursive functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_recursion). A tail-recursive function is one where the only recursive call is the result of the function. For example,

```
foldl f x (y:ys) = foldl f (f x y) ys
```

In contrast, `foldr` is not tail recursive

```
foldr f x (y:ys) = f y (foldr f x ys)
```

For technical reasons, a tail recursive call can re-use the stack frame of its caller, and thus does not cause the call stack to grow.

(A side note: `foldr` is not tail recursive but is "lazier" than `foldl`, because it may not need to evaluate the whole list. This may guide your decision on which to use.)

Even with a tail-recursive function, you may run out of memory due to a ["space leak"](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Performance/Space). For example, in `foldl` each recursive call will build a new suspension for `(f x y)`. `foldl` uses constant stack space, but O(n) space for unevaluated calls to `f`. To avoid this in cases where strictness is desirable, you can use `foldl'`

```
foldl' f x (y:ys) = (foldl' f $! f x y) ys
```

where the infix operator `$!` forces strict evaluation.

Comment: Have to say foldl also gives this error, though foldl' works well. Thank you for the explanation anyway!

Answer (score 3):

I don't know why [litb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/34509/litb) put his answer into a comment instead of an answer, so I'm copying it here so that people will see it:

http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Stack_overflow

I think it's the right answer.  But the short version is that foldr is not tail recursive.

I've marked this post as Community Wiki, so I won't get any reputation from it.